# how to convert byte array to image in ios

Tags: ios, uiimage, arrays, nsdata

today my task is convert byte array to image

First I try to convert image to byte array  :-

For converting Image to Byte array first we have to do is to convert that particular image [`UIImage`] to `NSData`.Then we will convert that `NSData` to Byte array. Here I will give the sample code, just go through...

```
//Converting UIImage to NSData
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"photo-04.jpg"];

    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

    //Converting NSData to Byte array
    NSUInteger len = [imageData length];
    NSLog(@"Byte Lendata1  %lu",(unsigned long)len);

    Byte *byteData = (Byte*)malloc(len);
    memcpy(byteData, [imageData bytes], len);
```

i am try  like this Convert byte to imageView

```
 const unsigned char *bytes = [imageData bytes];

    NSUInteger length = [imageData length];

    NSMutableArray *byteArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        [byteArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedChar:bytes[i]]];
    }
    NSDictionary *dictJson = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              byteArray, @"photo",
                              nil];
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictJson options:0 error:NULL];
    NSLog(@"");
    UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageWithData:jsonData];

    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 50)];


    imgView.image=image1;
```

I got output convert image to byte array but i want convert byte array to image
so please help me thanks in advanced.

Comment: just do the opposite. Show what you have tried.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks for replay i tried like this NSData *imageData1 = [NSData dataWithBytes:byteData length:len];
    
   
    
    UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData1];
    
    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 50)];
   imgView.image=image1;

Comment: Don't put your code in a comment. Update your question with your code.

Comment: @rmaddy add my code in question please help me

Comment: @HimanshuJoshi I have "photo-04.jpg" image in my app,i have converted the image into NSData and to byte data.And after that i have again converted back into NSData from byte data.I want to display my image in UIImageView from this NSData value.But it's not displayed. plz suggest me how to display.

Comment: does the @kukushi patch did not worked?

Comment: @HimanshuJoshi i  tried but image is not displayed

Answer (score 5):

First, you need to convert bytes to `NSData`

```
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithBytes:bytesData length:length];
```

Then, convert the data back to image.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

And I suggest you should first searching about the documentations when problems occur.

Here is all:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"RAC.png"];

NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
// UIImageJPGRepresentation also work

NSInteger length = [imageData length];

Byte *byteData = (Byte*)malloc(length);
memcpy(byteData, [imageData bytes], length);

NSData *newData = [NSData dataWithBytes:byteData length:length];

UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithData:newData];

UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:newImage];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 100);
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

Comment: @PavanAlapati Did you forget to add the imageView to the self.view as the subview? My answer work fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

You are representing the data with wrong **format**

Your image is of format `jpg` and you are representing with `PNG` data.

For `jpg` or `jpeg` format you should use `UIImageJPEGRepresentation`

```
NSData * UIImageJPEGRepresentation (
   UIImage *image,
   CGFloat compressionQuality
);
```

The required statement will be

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.0f);// Set Compression quality to 0.0. You can change it.
```

For `png` format you should use `UIImagePNGRepresentation`

```
NSData * UIImagePNGRepresentation (
   UIImage *image
);
```

The required statement will be

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
```

To convert the `NSData` back to `UIImage`, use

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

READ THE [APPLE DOCS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006894-CH3-SW28). SEE UNDER IMAGE MANIPULATION