# byte array to uiimageView in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiimageview

My requirement is that a local image will be converted to a byte array  and then the byte array is converted back to the image

i have done the image to Byte array conversion but i trying bytearray convert to image and then display on UIIMageView 
code is no error but Image Converted to byte array 
but byte array converted io image but image is not display 
please give me any idea

Here is what I have so far

```
   UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"shopper-home-copy_03.png"];




   //Output
   NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

    NSUInteger len = data.length;

    uint8_t *bytes = (uint8_t *)[data bytes];

    NSMutableString *result = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:len * 3];


    [result appendString:@"["];

    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (i)
        {

            [result appendString:@","];

        }

        [result appendFormat:@"%d", bytes[i]];
    }

    [result appendString:@"]"];
   NSMutableData *newdata = [NSMutableData new];
    NSScanner *theScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString: result];
    while ([theScanner isAtEnd] == NO) {
        int a;
        [theScanner scanInt:&a];
        uint8_t b = a;
        [newdata appendBytes:(const void *)&b length:1];
    }

    UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithData:newdata];
    self->imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:newImage];

    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 25 , 150,150);

    [self.view addSubview:self->imageView];
```

Comment: Have a look, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22316608/how-to-convert-byte-array-to-image-in-ios/22316710#comment33918939_22316710

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should check is [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) is suitable for you. If you still need your own format try following

```
NSMutableData *newData = [NSMutableData new];
NSScanner *theScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString: result];
theScanner.charactersToBeSkipped = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"[],"];
while ([theScanner isAtEnd] == NO) {
    int a;
    [theScanner scanInt:&a];
    uint8_t b = a;
    [newData appendBytes:(const void *)&b length:1];
}
UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithData:newData];
```

Comment: NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData new]; this line error

Comment: Redefinition of 'data' with a different type :'NSMutableData *_string' vs'NSdata *_string' this is error message

Comment: It is just because you already have `data` variable. I have renamed it with `newData` in the answer.

Comment: it's not Showing any error and then it's not Showing Image also please help me

Comment: I have just checked - everything works. Are you sure you did not forget to copy line `theScanner.charactersToBeSkipped = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"[],"];` ? I can not find it in code you copy-pasted to question.

Answer (score 0):

Create an NSData object from the byte array. And then use this

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to convert string to bytes array..

first step to convert mutable string to array.

```
NSArray *strings = [<mutableString> componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

unsigned c = strings.count; // strings is the array instance from the mutable string (separate using ",")
uint8_t *bytes = malloc(sizeof(*bytes) * c);

unsigned i;

for (i = 0; i < c; i++)

{
NSString *str = [strings objectAtIndex:i];

int byte = [str intValue];
bytes[i] = byte;
}
```

from bytes convert to image is as follows..

```
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:bytes length:c freeWhenDone:YES];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

reference from [Byte Array to NSData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11860830/byte-array-to-nsdata)

Comment: thanks fro Replay but i using NSMutableString                         unsigned c = strings.count;
NSString *str = [strings objectAtIndex:i]; this 2 lines are Error  please help me

Comment: Raja  propetry 'count' not found on Object of type 'NSmutbaleString *'
and NO Visible @interface for 'NSMutableString' declares the selecor 'objectAtIndex:'

Comment: Are you using `NSMutableString`?

Comment: @Raja Image is Not display

Answer (score 0):

Convert `byteArray` to `NSData` and then to `UIImage`

```
-(UIImage *)convertToImageFromByteArray:(NSMutableString*)mutableStr{

    NSArray *byteArray = [mutableStr componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

    unsigned c = byteArray.count;
    uint8_t *bytes = malloc(sizeof(*bytes) * c);

    unsigned i;
    for (i = 0; i < c; i++)
    {
        NSString *str = [byteArray objectAtIndex:i];
        int byte = [str intValue];
        bytes[i] = (uint8_t)byte;
    }

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:bytes length:c];

    return [UIImage imageWithData:data];
}
```

Comment: I want Byte array convert to image

Comment: You have said that you want to convert `NSMUtableString`

Comment: if you want to convert `byteArray` then simply change the function to `-(UIImage *)convertToImageFromByteArray:(NSArray*)byteArray` and remove the line `NSArray *byteArray = [mutableStr componentsSeparatedByString:@","];`.